# After installing windows10 ubuntu does not boot

Tags: windows

I used to have Windows 8 and ubuntu dual booted but after upgrading to Windows10 ubuntu does not booted and the system goes to Windows.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi  . Please read the ENTIRE first post including the "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS" section. If you still have a problem, update your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution is to run Ubuntu from flash drive, change the boot menu to USB 2nd on the boot option list this way dual boot screen will always show.